# How to remove all rows that contain character

Tags: r, regex

Im trying to remove all rows that contain a ? in any column in a data frame. I have 950 rows by 11 columns.
Ive tried this to do it all at once.

```
dataNew <- data %>% filter_all(all_vars(!grepl("?",.)))
```

and this to see if i could even get it to work for one column.

```
dataNew <- data[!grepl('?',data$column),]
```

Both of these attempts resulted in an empty dataframe. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `fixed = TRUE` as `?` is a metacharacter (or escape (`\\?`) or wrap it inside square bracket (`[?]`) when the default mode for `grep` is `fixed = FALSE`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    filter_all(all_vars(!grepl("?",., fixed = TRUE)))
#    col1 col2
#1    1    2
```

---

Or using `across` from the `devel` version of `dplyr`

```
data %>% 
    filter(across(everything(), ~ !grepl("?", ., fixed = TRUE)))
#  col1 col2
#1    1    2
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
data[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(data, grepl, pattern = '?', fixed = TRUE)),]
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(col1 = c("?", 1, 3, "?"), col2 = c(1, 2, "?", "?"),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```